# Golang reflect, how to get map value type?

Tags: go, reflection

For a map `m` in golang, we can get simply the key type using `t.Key()`.

But I wonder how to get the map value type?

When the map is empty, we can not even use `v.MapIndex`, any idea?

```
m := map[string]int{}
t := reflect.TypeOf(m)
v := reflect.ValueOf(m)
t.Key()
v.MapIndex()
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Go has strong typing, which means that the type is determined at compile time. Thus it should be clear for the developer what type it is.

Comment: Because sometime we need to reflect.New the key and value, and inject value for each pair.

Answer (score 21):

`Elem()` of a map type will give you the element's type:

```
var m map[string]int
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(m).Elem())
// output: int
```

Comment: Great answer, but I would love to see a version that's not contingent on the reflect package.

Answer (score 9):

Here an example to get the type of the map keys and map elements:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var m map[string]int
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(m).Key())
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(m).Elem())
}
```

Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/0HHUt19fqC6)

Doc is here https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type